# How to pass expected and actual value in paramererized test in JUnit 5

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to implement Parameterized test in which I have a set of input and expected values which I want to test using `assertEquals` method of `JUnit`. **I'm using JUnit version 5.x for this** I am passing the input value to my custom method defined in other package (that I'm testing) and I am checking it with an expected value with `assertEquals` method.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

class StringHelperTest {
    private StringHelper helper = new StringHelper();
    private String input;
    private String expectedOutput;

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String getExpectedOutput() {
        return expectedOutput;
    }

    public void setExpectedOutput(String expectedOutput) {
        this.expectedOutput = expectedOutput;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<String[]> testConditions() {
        String[][] expectedOutputs = { { "AACD", "CD" }, { "ACD", "CD" }, { "CDEF", "CDEF" }, { "CDAA", "CDAA" } };
        return Arrays.asList(expectedOutputs);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @Test
    public void truncateAInFirst2Positions_A_atStart() {
        assertEquals(expectedOutput, helper.truncateAInFirst2Positions(input));

    }
}
```

In the method `testConditions()` the actual and expected values are given as a 2 dimensinonal String array `expectedOutputs` {{<actual_value>,<expected_value>},{...}}.

How do I pass `expectedOutputs` array to the `truncateAInFirst2Positions_A_atStart()` method to test all conditions mentioned in `expectedOutputs` array

Comment: In general, you should only provide input to your methods as parameters, not the expected results.

Comment: Ok that I know I can provide with @ValueSource annotation in JUnit5 but then how do I check if the returned string is my expected one or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With JUnit 5 you have ParameterizedTest and a Source for the input parameters, which are simple the parameters of the method.

So you want a Method with this signature:

```
@ParameterizedTest
//Source Annotation
void truncateAInFirst2Positions_A_atStart(String actual, String expected) {
```

And now you look up a for your use case matching source. When you want to proivde your test data with your method you could use `@MethodSource("testConditions")`. The String in the annotation points to the static method providing your test data. The test will be executed x times where x is the count of pairs in your collection. The elements in your String Array will be used as method arguments.

For simple types like Strings a CSV source can be simpler and easier to read:

```
@CsvSource({
"AACD, CD",
"ACD, CD"
})
```

You can check all possible sources and possiblites in the offcial documentation:
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests

Comment: @CsvSource does the work fine without the additional function Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference as the question is already answered, but if you need something else than strings (e.g. your own objects) you can use [`org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments.arguments`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.7.2/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/Arguments.html#arguments(java.lang.Object...)), e.g.:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("provideMyObject")
void myTestMethod(ActualObject actual, ExpectedObject expected) {
   // ...
}

static Stream<Arguments> provideMyObject() {
    return Stream.of(
            org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments.arguments(new ActualObject("foo"), new ExpectedObject("foo")),
            org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments.arguments(new ActualObject("bar"), new ExpectedObject("bar))
    );
}
```

see also: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource

Comment: Thank you! Just what I've been looking for. Underrated answer :)